# In which tournament did Sergio Garcia spit into the hole?

Tags: golf, match-identification

I remember one time Sergio Garcia spat into the hole after retrieving the ball out of the hole. Can anybody identify which tournament this took place at? I don't remember if this was before or after his win at the players.

Answer (score 1):

Sergio Garcia Garcia literally spit into the **pin cup** after retrieving his ball at the **13th hole** during the **third round of the CA Championship.**

Source: [ESPN](http://www.espn.in/golf/columns/story?columnist=kreidler_mark&id=2814226)

Answer (score 0):

From this [stltoday.com](https://www.stltoday.com/sports/spitting-in-sports-is-common-act/article_7cda1f80-392f-11e0-96d0-00127992bc8b.html) article:

> ... on the 13th hole at the CA Championship at Doral Country Club, Garcia spit into the pin cup after retrieving his ball.

[Youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DS6dA6ngKok)